# "What to do on top of" or "what to do on the top of"?

Tags: word-choice

Example:

> I had to find something to keep myself
>   busy. But what to do on (the) top of a mountain?

Is "on top of a mountain" or "on the top of a mountain"? right choice? Why?

Comment: It might depend on how pointy the mountain is. Some are so pointy you can't really get "on top", or let's say they don't have a "top" that's big enough or flat enough to "do" anything but maintain your balance. A phrasing that might work well for any shape of mountain is "at the top of a mountain".

Comment: The whole phrase reads slightly strange to me:  Perhaps "I had to find something to keep busy, but (really) what is there to do on top of a mountain?"  You could also use "..., but what to do on a mountain top?" and it flows slightly better.